How to retrieve JSON data from MySQL by cursor?
I have a table which storing JSON data in it,
Table Services
| ID| Details             | Time 
| A | {a:"2",b:"2",c:"3"} | 16-06-2024 00:00:00 |
| A | {a:"2",b:"4",c:"5"} | 16-06-2024 00:30:00 |
| A | {a:"3",b:"4",c:"0"} | 16-06-2024 01:00:00 |
| A | {a:"3",b:"0",c:"0"} | 16-06-2024 01:30:00 |
| B | {a:"6",b:"2",c:"2"} | 16-06-2024 00:00:00 |
| B | {a:"2",b:"4",c:"6"} | 16-06-2024 00:30:00 |
| B | {a:"3",b:"4",c:"0"} | 16-06-2024 01:00:00 |
| B | {a:"3",b:"0",c:"0"} | 16-06-2024 01:30:00 |


I am searching ways to
first, using cursor to use [JSON_EXTRACT(Services, '$.(JSON keys)') as (JSON keys)] to turn the JSON keys as column name and JSON values as values respectively
secondly, using SUBSTRING to get hourly average.
I want the result like this:



ID
a
b
c
Time




A
2
3
4
16-06-2024 00:00:00


A
3
2
0
16-06-2024 01:00:00


B
4
3
4
16-06-2024 00:00:00


B
3
2
0
16-06-2024 01:00:00




which mysql version are you using Mysql 8 has introduced JSON_TABLE see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/json-table-functions.html

Is the list of possible JSON keys defined? or it is dynamic and can be expanded?
